# Bus arrival probability...

Tags: probability, statistics, descriptive-statistics

This question has two parts,

**Question one**

A municipal bus system, when operating perfectly on time, provide at any given bus stop every 30 min. A person arrive at a random time at bus stop. What is the average waiting time until the next bus arrives?

**The Answer**

Since buses are following uniform distribution the average waiting time will be 15 min.

**Question two**

If the busses become totally disorganized and random following Poisson random process what will be the average waiting time given that number of buses remains content

I know the answer is 1/lambda, but how to find the lambda, is it still 15 min since the same number of busses are running. Can someone explain this to me!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, that you have to wait on average 15 minutes if the arrival time is uniformly distributed as $X\sim U(0,30)$

The expected value is $E(X)=\int_0^{30} \frac{x}{30} \, dx=\frac1{60}\cdot (900-0)=15$

Let the arrival time  poisson distributed where the expected number of buses is  $1$ per 30 minutes ($\lambda=\frac1{30}$). The pdf that we observe $k$ buses in  $t>0$ minutes is

$$P(N(t)=k)=e^{-\frac1{30}\cdot t} \frac{\left(\frac1{30}\cdot t\right)^k}{k!}$$

The expected value is $\frac{t}{30}$. That means that we have to wait on average $30$ minutes for one bus ($t=30$). We have to recognize that the waiting time between two bus stops can be **larger than 30 minutes (t>0)**. There is no cut-off at $30$ minutes as in the case of the uniformly distributed variable since $P(X>30)=0$. For instance the probability that one bus does not arrive in the first 30 minutes but in the second half an hour is positive:

$$P(N(30)=0 \cap N(60)=1)=e^{-\frac1{30}\cdot 30}\cdot \frac{\left(\frac1{30}\cdot 30\right) ^0}{0!} \cdot e^{-\frac1{30}\cdot 30}\cdot \frac{\left(\frac1{30}\cdot 30\right) ^1}{1!}$$

$$e^{-1}\cdot \frac{\left(1\right) ^0}{0!} \cdot e^{-1}\cdot \frac{\left(1\right) ^1}{1!}\approx 13.53\%$$

Answer (score 1):

The number of buses remains constant, so on average we still have 1 bus / 30 minutes, or 1/30 buses per minute. This is $\lambda$ assuming minute as your time interval.